# Under which identity a custom webpart runs, user or application pool?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

As the question says, when you deploy a webpart and access it from sharepoint, it runs in current user identity or app pool ?

Answer (score 1):

Any code in the web part will run in the context of the current user unless it has blocks where privileges have been elevated. This is commonly done using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` which runs code in the context of the App Pool account. The constructor of the `SPSite` object in the SharePoint Server Object Model also enables you to run code in the context of a specific user by passing a `SPUserToken` as a parameter.

See these blog posts for more information.

[Best Practices for Elevated Privilege in SharePoint](https://daniellarson.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/best-practices-for-elevated-privilege-in-sharepoint/)

[Elevated Privilege with SPSite](https://daniellarson.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/elevated-privilege-with-spsite/)

Answer (score 0):

It runs as the app pool identity.